# What is the trace of the (spatial) projection tensor?

Tags: general-relativity, tensor-calculus, linear-algebra

In the discussion on gravitational waves in Moore's A General Relativity Workbook, Box 33.4 on page 391 introduces the projection operator

$$P^j_m\equiv\delta^j_m - n^jn_m$$

where $\vec n$ is a unit vector. In the accompanying Student Manual, Moore says to note that

$$P^j_j=\delta^j_j - n^jn_j=3-2=1$$

Is this correct? Doesn't $n^jn_j=1$ for a unit vector, so that

$$P^j_j=\delta^1_1+\delta^2_2+\delta^3_3 - 1=3-1=2$$

What am I missing?

Comment: A projection always has $\text{Tr}P=\text{dim} N$ where $N$ is the dimension of the subspace it is projecting to.

I don't know this reference, but if $P$ is a three-dimensional tensor and is of the form you have given, then yes, it should have trace $2$.